# Controller is not available using https-remoting protocol

Tags: https, wildfly, wildfly-8, jboss-cli

I am trying to deploy my war archive on 8.0.0 final jboss redhat RPM. Everything was working fine until I tried to enable my security options. I have added both `<ssl>` tag and `<trustore>` tag under SecurityRealm. In addition I added an `<https-listener>` and enabled the https-management console.

I've added a controller to jboss-cli.xml as follows:

```
 <controllers>
        <controller name="MyHttpsController">
            <protocol>https-remoting</protocol>
            <host>myHost</host>
            <port>myPort</port>
        </controller>
 </controllers>
```

I'm executing the jboss server process by runnning the standalone.sh script and then I'm trying to deploy my war by using the following line:

**./jboss-cli.sh --connect=MyHttpsController** command="deploy [myWarPath]"

**I get the following error:**

*The controller is not available at myIp:myPort: java.net.ConnectException:
.....**The connection timed out***

I can open the https-management console via the browser and I checked that my server is actually listening to this port. Please help my if you can, this is very important.

I appreciate all help you can give me.

Thanks all, 
Michael

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the default-protocol tag also has https-remoting in the jboss-cli.xml file.

Replace

```
<default-protocol use-legacy-override="true">http-remoting</default-protocol>
```

by

```
<default-protocol use-legacy-override="true">https-remoting</default-protocol>
```